# how to ingress correctly in kuberenetes with nginx-ingress

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, dhcp, nginx-ingress

I'm new to k8s and I'm having slight trouble setting up a local cluster on virtual machines and have it be accessible from at least my host machine.

#### setup.

- I've a local cluster consisting of three debian virtual machines with 1 master and 2 workers. I had created a virtual interface with CIDR `10.0.0.0/16` and I had set the dhcp domain to be `abcd.com`.
- I created my cluster I set `clusterDNS: abcd.com`, `podCIDR: 69.96.0.0/16` and `serviceCIDR: 69.97.0.0/16`. I am using cilium CNI & coreDNS corefile.

```yaml
.:53 {
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes abcd.com in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
```

- I deployed a `nginx-pod` in default namespace and created a service `nginx-svc` of type `NodePort` that exposed `nginx-pod` on port `80`. I created an ingress rule that had a rule to forward `abdc.com` to `nginx-svc`.
- I then installed `ingress-nginx-controller`

#### logs.

- Corefile for coreDNS:

```yaml
ayush@ip-10-0-191-144:~$ kubectl describe ingress/example
Name:             example
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  abcd.com
                 /   nginx-svc:80 (69.96.1.111:80)
Annotations:     <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    30m (x5 over 11h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

- services:

```bash
ayush@ip-10-0-191-144:~$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP      69.97.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      2d14h
default         nginx-svc                            NodePort       69.97.216.124   <none>        80:30744/TCP                 26h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   69.97.88.241    <pending>     80:31565/TCP,443:32581/TCP   2d2h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      69.97.200.46    <none>        443/TCP                      2d2h
kube-system     cilium-agent                         ClusterIP      None            <none>        9964/TCP                     2d14h
kube-system     hubble-metrics                       ClusterIP      None            <none>        9965/TCP                     2d14h
kube-system     hubble-peer                          ClusterIP      69.97.190.83    <none>        443/TCP                      2d14h
kube-system     hubble-relay                         ClusterIP      69.97.188.92    <none>        80/TCP                       2d14h
kube-system     hubble-ui                            ClusterIP      69.97.9.207     <none>        80/TCP                       2d14h
kube-system     kube-dns                             ClusterIP      69.97.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       2d14h
```

- pods:

```bash
ayush@ip-10-0-191-144:~$ kubectl get pods -A -o wide
NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE     IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default         dnsutils                                    1/1     Running   1 (11h ago)    11h     69.96.2.47     ip-10-0-94-54     <none>           <none>
default         nginx-pod                                   1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    26h     69.96.1.111    ip-10-0-38-41     <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-55474d95c5-f4kfx   1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d3h    69.96.1.80     ip-10-0-38-41     <none>           <none>
kube-system     cilium-428bt                                1/1     Running   7 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.38.41     ip-10-0-38-41     <none>           <none>
kube-system     cilium-8hpbb                                1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     cilium-cxgnc                                1/1     Running   6 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.94.54     ip-10-0-94-54     <none>           <none>
kube-system     cilium-operator-6cdc4568cb-gg58q            1/1     Running   39 (11h ago)   2d14h   10.0.38.41     ip-10-0-38-41     <none>           <none>
kube-system     cilium-operator-6cdc4568cb-k7nsd            1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-76f75df574-45f7b                    1/1     Running   9 (11h ago)    2d14h   69.96.0.43     ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     coredns-76f75df574-77m4h                    1/1     Running   9 (11h ago)    2d14h   69.96.0.221    ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     etcd-ip-10-0-191-144                        1/1     Running   11 (11h ago)   2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     hubble-relay-d8b6b55c9-st57x                1/1     Running   9 (11h ago)    2d11h   69.96.2.197    ip-10-0-94-54     <none>           <none>
kube-system     hubble-ui-6548d56557-b6f49                  2/2     Running   9 (11h ago)    2d11h   69.96.2.93     ip-10-0-94-54     <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-apiserver-ip-10-0-191-144              1/1     Running   11 (11h ago)   2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-ip-10-0-191-144     1/1     Running   11 (11h ago)   2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-7gc2j                            1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.94.54     ip-10-0-94-54     <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-xt8nc                            1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-proxy-xzjjj                            1/1     Running   4 (11h ago)    2d14h   10.0.38.41     ip-10-0-38-41     <none>           <none>
kube-system     kube-scheduler-ip-10-0-191-144              1/1     Running   11 (11h ago)   2d14h   10.0.191.144   ip-10-0-191-144   <none>           <none>
```

#### questions.

1. Even though `nginx-ingress-controller` shows `Running`. It doesn't get an external ip & is stuck on `<pending>`. **I'm not sure why!!** (you can see above in service logs)
2. From any node's ip, I'm able to access the nginx-svc by doing `curl -H 'Host: isitayush.dev' -X 10.0.191.144:31565` but how can I make it such that i can simply reach to my nginx-svc via any of the node's external ip? (i.e. 10.0.191.144 [my master node ip] should route me to the `nginx-svc` or `nginx-pod`)

> Can I switch `nginx-ingress-controller` port `31565` to `80` & `443` or some other port such that I can use the node external ip and still reach to my defined service within the rule?

3. Is it also possible to reach the `nginx-pod` by the domain name `abcd.com` or better yet something different such as `pqrs.com` externally? Given I own `pqrs.com` and it has an A record that points to the external load balancer ip or one of the node's ip for `nginx-ingress-controller`?

> My final goal would be to set an A record & point multiple domains that I own to this cluster (a external load balancer than balances between the ip's of all nodes or just of the pods) and then have my `nginx-ingress-handler` route them to the appropriate service through the `ingress` rules. Is it possible to do so? I'll deploy this on AWS (I want to try to avoid their load balancer service in this setup if possible).

4. Can I make "dhcp domain" & "cluster dns" domain seperate. For example, in my interface settings, I could set `abcd.com` and when creating a cluster I'll set `pqrs.com`?

Thank you!